# Add currency symbol to JQGrid Sub Total

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jqgrid

I have a Jqgrid on my ASP web page and I am trying to format one of the columns to so that it prefixes the "price" value with a pound sign.

I have tried a number of different approaches.

Firstly I have attempted to set the DataFormatString value on the grid itself, however this breaks the grouped sub total sum. It just returns NaN, presumably because it cant sum a currency value.

```
<trirand:JQGridColumn DataField="price" Editable="false" GroupSummaryType="Sum" DataFormatString="{0:c}">
```

I have then looked into options for stripping the formatting and reinstating it using the following functions, but with limited success.

```
function currencyFmatter (cellvalue, options, rowObject)
{
   return "$"+cellvalue;
}
function  unformatCurrency (cellvalue, options) 
{
   return cellvalue.replace("$","");
}
```

My current attempt is to edit the format of the gridview column using the below script. However when I run my program it does nothing. The numbers remain formatted as they were i.e 10.00

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    grid = $("#JQGrid2");
    grid.jqGrid({
    colModel : [
        {
            name: 'price', formatter: 'currency',
            formatoptions: { prefix: '(£ ', thousandsSeparator: ',' }
        },
    ],
    });
</script>
```

What's the simplest way to add a currency symbol to my sub total field?

Below is the current ASP code for my Grid.

```
 <trirand:JQGridColumn DataField="price" Editable="false" GroupSummaryType="Sum" DataFormatString="{0:c}">

        <trirand:JQGrid runat="server" ID="JQGrid2" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" Width="1200px" Height="100%" maxHeight="300" hidegrid="true" ondatarequested="JQGrid2_DataRequested">
            <Columns>
                <trirand:JQGridColumn CSSClass="indent" DataField="description" Editable="true" Width="1200"/>
                <trirand:JQGridColumn DataField="inv_section" Editable="true" />
                <trirand:JQGridColumn DataField="ref_date_start" Editable="true" DataFormatString="{0:d}" />
                <trirand:JQGridColumn DataField="ref_date_end" Editable="true" DataFormatString="{0:d}" />
                <trirand:JQGridColumn DataField="cust_po" Editable="true" />
                <trirand:JQGridColumn DataField="unit_sell" Editable="true" DataFormatString="{0:c}"/>  
                <trirand:JQGridColumn DataField="qty" Editable="true"/>
                <trirand:JQGridColumn DataField="price" Editable="false" >
        </trirand:JQGridColumn>      
            </Columns>
            <AppearanceSettings ShowFooter="true" />
            <ToolBarSettings ShowEditButton="true" ShowRefreshButton="True" ShowAddButton="true" ShowDeleteButton="true" ShowSearchButton="True" />
        </trirand:JQGrid>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

The subTotal is configurable is with summaryTpl option in colModel, where you can put what you want including Dollar. JavaScript [demo here](http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/grouping/summary_and_grand_total/index.html)